# Open Password Protected Access Database

Tags: c#, ms-access

Attempting to use C# to open a password protected access database.  I have tried both of these options to open my database, but both of them produce a compile error of

```
No overload method for OpenCurrentDatabase takes 3 arguments
```

But if you look at the MSDN for VBA it shows it does take 3 arguments?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837226(v=office.15).aspx

```
Access.Application AccApp = new Access.Application();
AccApp.Visible = true;
//AccApp.OpenCurrentDatabase(databasePathAndFileName, false, "MS Access;pwd=" databasePassword);
AccApp.OpenCurrentDatabase(databasePathAndFileName, false, databasePassword);
```

.
.
.
.
.
EDIT --
See attached screenshot that references error I receive
[image]

Comment: Your documentation is referring to VBA, but your tags mention C#. Which are you actually using? They're not the same thing, and neither are the methods you use.

Comment: @KenWhite the method signature should be the same.

Comment: Your code sample doesn't compile, but not because of the argument count.  Are you sure that the sample matches your code?

Comment: @phoog that is just a snippet of the error lines.  I you add the variables databasePathAndFilename and databasepassword it will only give you the compilation error of the OpenCurrentDatabase line

Comment: But your third argument has two tokens -- a string literal and a string variable.  The compile error is ") expected".  Did you mean to have a `+` between them?

Comment: I noticed another odd thing -- there is no type called `AccApplication` defined in the MS Access COM object model.  The VBA documentation is only useful if you're using types generated from the COM reference.  Is that a clue or a typing error?  What code library are you actually using?

Comment: @phoog that was simply a typo on that note.

Comment: Well at this point all I can suggest is to post a short complete program that reproduces the "no overload..." error, since I cannot reproduce it.

Comment: I am unable to recreate your issue using "Microsoft Access 14.0 Object Library" (Access 2010) as a project reference. It appears in my project as "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access". The `OpenCurrentDatabase` method definitely will accept three arguments (one required and two optional).

Answer (score -2):

Take out the double backslashes and replace them with single backslashes.

```
app.OpenCurrentDatabase("C:\OpenMe\Database\Test.mdb", false, "hitheretom");
```

Comment: Sorry, but no. To create a C# string literal with backslashes in it you need to use either `"C:\\thing"` or `@"C:\thing"`.

Comment: That's odd, because my copy of C# (2010) complains that `\O`, `\D`, and `\T` are all "Unrecognized escape sequences" and the build fails.

Comment: The only way (in my experience) it will work with single slashes is adding the @ symbol in front of the strong so using @"C:\OpenMe\Database\Test.mdb" would allow the use of single slashes.